# Index rows in Pandas Dataframe not in List of Indexes (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, indexing

I am trying to index rows of Dataframe with rows **not included** in the list. For example, here we extract rows 1,2 and 4 of the dataframe (data). But I would like to extract everything but those rows (say rows 3, 5, and 6):

```
idx = [1,3,4]
subset= data.iloc[idx , :]
```

So far, I tried this but get the error below:

```
try = data.iloc[not idx, :]
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.loc[~ data.index.isin(idx)]
```